# Bypass colorbox X-Frame-Options restrictions

Tags: colorbox, x-frame-options

I have an almost similar question as [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options/6767901#6767901) but what if the URL is external and not on the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it creating an nginx proxy with proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options